# Is it possible to load the contents of a generated bundle in another module in webpack?

Tags: webpack

I'm looking to load a generated JS bundle as a string from another module (one that isn't included in the aforementioned bundle — i.e. no circular dependencies).

Something ideally like this:

---

#### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    foo: 'foo.js',
    bar: 'bar.js',
  }
  ...
}
```

#### bar.js

```
import fooContents from '<something that gets me foo>'

console.log(fooContents);
```

---

I was thinking I might need to write a custom loader (e.g. `import fooContents from 'my-loader!?bundle=foo'`) or even a custom plugin, but I'm hoping something like that already exists. After looking through webpack-contrib and other places, I haven't found anything though :-/

Comment: I assume I'd need to do something very similar to what [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader/) does, but I'm hoping someone's already done this..

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I indeed ended up forking `worker-loader`, which spins up a child compiler.